# HTTP/2 results in 404 for images and fonts

Tags: wordpress, png, http-status-code-404, jpeg, http2

**What I did:** I tweaked a Wordpress website so it will load within 2.3 seconds instead of the former 5 seconds. As a final step, I enabled HTTP/2 in the LAMP server (PHP7.0, Apache 2.4) and restarted Apache.

**Issues:** On doing this, the Time to First Byte jumped from 500ms to 9 seconds and the website PNG and JPEG images in the Speed Load Test (GTmetrix and Webpagetest.org) are now resulting in 404. Please, see screenshot here https://www.diigo.com/item/image/5pj5q/vt0g

Overall, the Speed Load Test is showing me that the website is loading at 20-30 seconds, instead of the former 2.3 seconds.

I am at a loss about how to solve those two issues caused by HTTP/2. Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found the answer. It has to do with SSL Certs. At least for my situation. I use WHM/CPanel and the SSL certs get shared. HTTP2 detects that and sends a 421 error.

From Apache : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_http2.html

> Multiple Hosts and Misdirected Requests
>
> Many sites use the same TLS certificate for multiple virtual hosts.
>   The certificate either has a wildcard name, such as '*.example.org' or
>   carries several alternate names. Browsers using HTTP/2 will recognize
>   that and reuse an already opened connection for such hosts.
>
> While this is great for performance, it comes at a price: such vhosts
>   need more care in their configuration. The problem is that you will
>   have multiple requests for multiple hosts on the same TLS connection.
>   And that makes renegotiation impossible, in face the HTTP/2 standard
>   forbids it.
>
> So, if you have several virtual hosts using the same certificate and
>   want to use HTTP/2 for them, you need to make sure that all vhosts
>   have exactly the same SSL configuration. You need the same protocol,
>   ciphers and settings for client verification.
>
> If you mix things, Apache httpd will detect it and return a special
>   response code, 421 Misdirected Request, to the client.

I disabled http2 and the 404/421 errors stopped.